# wordpress ajax error: unable to post meta data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

There may be a simple solution for this but I am struggling to solve the issue.

I have been working on a wordpress plugin to print post(here the post type is woocommerce `product`) meta data on the page where the user will have a input text field to trigger the function from product page. I am using AJAX here to send the input data to my wordpress function.

The problem is when I tested the the code with some mocked up junk data it worked fine but the code is not sending out any data when I use to call post meta using `get_post_meta`.
Is there anything to be applied in case we are calling post meta through AJAX?I sharing my code below.

**Code in wordpress:**

```
add_action('init', 'timeslot_ajax_handle');

function timeslot_ajax_handle() {
    wp_register_script("timeslot_ajax_script", um_product_url . 'assets/js/timeslot_ajax.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('timeslot_ajax_script', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('timeslot_ajax_script');
}

add_action("wp_ajax_timeslot_ajax_submit", "timeslot_ajax_submit");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_timeslot_ajax_submit", "timeslot_ajax_submit");

function timeslot_ajax_submit() {
    //function to process ajax requests from product page
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], "submitted_date")) {
        exit("An error occured");
    }
    global $wpdb, $post, $product, $woocommerce;
    $product_id = $_REQUEST["post_id"];
    $bookdate = $_REQUEST["bookdate"];
    $result['type'] = "success";
    $result['result_text'] = get_post_meta($product_id, '_total_sales', true);

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
    } else {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }

    die();
}
```

**Code for AJAX:**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

    jQuery("#datepicker_input").change( function() {
        jQuery('#day_timeslots_list').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery('#fountainH').css('display', 'block');

        var bookdate = jQuery('#dp_input').val();
        // alert(bookdate);
        post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id");
        nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce");

        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: "timeslot_ajax_submit", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce, bookdate: bookdate},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.type === "success") {
                    jQuery('#fountainH').css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#day_timeslots_list').css('display',     'block');
                    jQuery("#timeslot_active").html(response.result_text);
                } else {
                    alert("There is an error");
                }
            }
        }); 

        jQuery('#fountainH').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please describe.

Comment: @Sina:I am not getting any errors, the target element is just blank with out any output.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(response);` right after `success: function(response) { ...` and let us know what you see in your console?

Comment: Here is the log I got in console `Object {type: "success", result_text: ""}`

Comment: this line ```get_post_meta($product_id, '_total_sales', true);``` seems to be the issue, I am not sure about ```_total_sales``` postmeta if its a built woocommerce meta? I think its ```total_sales``` , I could be wrong though

Comment: @silver: I tried the same scenario with some other post meta data as well, but not working.

Comment: why don't you check your database and check the actual meta key

Comment: @silver: the keys are pretty much correct as I have been using the same keys in many other functions. the issue occurs only when I use any meta data irrespective of the key I use.

Comment: if the key is correct and the ID your are sending on ajax exist then I can't see any reason why it won't work, test your function without ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97110/discussion-between-krishna89-and-silver).